# Отладка подпрограммы на ассемблере

Tags: отладка, ассемблер, visual-studio, c++

Подпрограмма вызывается из C++ (консольное приложение в MS Visual Studio). Есть ли инструменты для этой отладки? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Олли. Не - нравится, так а что вы хотели, процессор не скрипт исполняет :D

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный встроенный отладчик Visual Studio поддерживает [отладку](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xzd549xs.aspx) встроенного ассемблера. Чтобы использовать отладку по исходному коду, надо собрать его с [опцией](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2wbeyy18.aspx) /Zi.